# Which points makes sql queries faster

Tags: mysql, sql, query-performance

I am very new for SQL codes, I choose only a few columns and use mostly `GROUP BY` function but my code takes 2 minutes to show result maybe it is not a long query but I need to make faster. How can I make an SQL query faster?

For my code, I have a table that has Leagues matches;

**Ex:**

```
CustomerID        MatchDate         League              Matches                HomeTeam                AwayTeam
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1                 11-12-2006        La Liga             Barcelone-R.Madrid     Barcelona               RealMadrid
2                 10-10-2006        Premier League      Everton-Arsenal        Everton                 Arsenal
3                 09-10-2006        Premier League      Arsenal-Tottenham      Barcelona               RealMadrid
4                 10-10-2006        Bundesliga          Bayern-Mainz           Bayern                  MainZ
```

My goal is, count total ID for each Match give for HomeTeam and AwayTeam for finding total watchs for each team and group by leagues, and Teams and Seasons. 
Same teams can be HomeTeam and AwayTeam so I used This code.

```
SELECT League, SUM(totalnum), Teams, Season FROM 
    (
        (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(MatchDate, '%Y') as 'Season', HomeTeam as Teams, League, count(distinct CustomerID) as "totalnum" 
            FROM MY_TABLE GROUP BY League, Teams, Season ) 
        UNION ALL 
        (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(MatchDate, '%Y') as 'Season', AwayTeam as Teams, League, count(distinct CustomerID) as "totalnum" 
            FROM MY_TABLE GROUP BY League, Teams, Season )
    ) aa
GROUP BY League, Teams, Season
ORDER BY totalnum DESC
```

I can get result but I need shorter. Which points can affect my query.

Comment: How many rows in the table?

Comment: Make sure you have indexes for your query.

Comment: almost a milion rows

Comment: indexes will be of no use, the OP needs all rows - no "where clause"

Comment: Before comment please check code @GerardH.Pille

Comment: @Axis  I did, and did it again: you are selecting all rows twice, so indexes will be of no use.

Comment: I think you could halve the time it takes by selecting the data only once, and unpivot on hometeam and awayteam: for each row read, you will return two.

Comment: @Axis you write `count(distinct ID)` so I guess in `MY_TABLE` the same customerID appears multiple times, but you want to count unique customerID. And question: IF CustomerID=1 watches a match in which Barcelona is awayteam, and CustomerID=1 also watches a match in which Barcelona is hometeam, how the CustomerID=1should be count on team=Barcelona? In your query, ID=1 counts twice.

Comment: @noymer Sorry, the example table looks not clear but I can explain.  ID column is each person id's that watched per Match so a person can watch many match during the Season. I gave you just 4 rows and 1.2.3.4 it can be any ID number. Also I changed my code as well please check now

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Even if a query in principally a `full table scan` it can still benefit from indexes.  In this case Indexes can avoid the need for a sort step that would currently be required due to the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Another observation though, is that in your query you `COUNT()` the unique "home customers" and then `COUNT()` the unique "away customers", then `SUM()` them.  Which means anyone that's been to a home match AND an away match counts twice.  Is that intended?

Comment: @MatBailie This is a good point. I need actually the SUM() because the results show home and away team separate but I tried to use only one count (only one match so each same number ) I got error

Comment: @MatBailie I disagree: reading data from a sizeable table whilst following the indexes will be a lot slower than sorting the data you extracted with a full table scan.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille If the query can be satisfied by a covering index that has been built in the correct order required to fulfill the calculations, the `INDEX SCAN` would normally have a lower or equal cost to the `TABLE SCAN`. Only if the index has insufficient coverage *(and so needs to join back to the underlying table)* would an `INDEX SCAN` usually yield a higher cost than `TABLE SCAN`. This plus the removal of a `SORT` step means that ***yes*** an index ***can*** give reduced cost. *(Note that I qualify my sentences, you make absolute/categorical statements, which are rarely always true)*

Comment: @MatBailie "you make absolute statements", true, but that is because I only have over 30 years experience with SQL, and so I don't have much time left to waste.  Please integrate into your performance stats the time needed to keep your index up to date.  I don't know about other RDBMS, but Oracle has an index organised table, to which your theory could apply.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Your 30 years, my 15 years, neither matter.  I have seen empirical evidence that there exists a set of cases which can be more cheaply solved with `FULL INDEX SCAN` than with `FULL TABLE SCAN`.  On the note about the cost of index maintenance, that's a much wider discussion than one query: How often is data written and what is the increased cost, how often are queries executed and what is the saved cost, do the indexes benefit other queries, would a trigger/derived table/etc be a better solution.  ***ALL*** indexes incur write costs, it sounds like you made a straw man argument.

Comment: Please read this and pay special attention to the section on query performance. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/ Please [edit] your question to provide a few more details.

Comment: I wouldn't bother with the subquery aggregation

Comment: Using InnoDB?  How much RAM?  How big is `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?

Answer (score 2):

If you apply these two indexes, I would expect your existing query should speed up...

```
CREATE INDEX MY_TABLE_league_home_date_cust
    ON MY_TABLE(
        League, HomeTeam, MatchDate, CustomerID
    );

CREATE INDEX MY_TABLE_league_away_date_cust
    ON MY_TABLE(
        League, AwayTeam, MatchDate, CustomerID
    );
```

That said, I suspect the highest cost involved in your query is the `COUNT(DISTINCT CustomerID)`.  Doing that involves having to sort all the data.  This *may* mean that the following indexes could be better...

```
CREATE INDEX MY_TABLE_cust_league_home_date
    ON MY_TABLE(
        CustomerID, League, HomeTeam, MatchDate
    );

CREATE INDEX MY_TABLE_cust_league_away_date
    ON MY_TABLE(
        CustomerID, League, AwayTeam, MatchDate
    );
```

Another observation though, is that in your query you `COUNT()` the unique "home customers" and then `COUNT()` the unique "away customers", then `SUM()` them.  Which means anyone that's been to a home match AND an away match counts twice.  Is that intended?

If that's not intended, you might find the cost of your query is even higher...

```
SELECT
  Team,
  League,
  DATE_FORMAT(MatchDate, '%Y')   AS Season,
  COUNT(DISTINCT CustomerID)     AS total
FROM 
(
  SELECT CustomerID, League, HomeTeam AS Team, MatchDate FROM MyTable
  UNION ALL
  SELECT CustomerID, League, AwayTeam AS Team, MatchDate FROM MyTable
)
  combined_view
GROUP BY
  Team, League, Season
ORDER BY
  total DESC
```

I think your overall best bet though is to add a computed column for the `Season` and then use a slightly modified version of the first indexes...

```
ALTER TABLE
  MY_TABLE
ADD Season VARCHAR(4) AS (
  DATE_FORMAT(MatchDate, '%Y')
);

CREATE INDEX MY_TABLE_league_home_season_cust
    ON MY_TABLE(
        League, HomeTeam, Season, CustomerID
    );

CREATE INDEX MY_TABLE_league_away_season_cust
    ON MY_TABLE(
        League, AwayTeam, Season, CustomerID
    );

SELECT
  Team,
  League,
  Season,
  COUNT(DISTINCT CustomerID)     AS total
FROM 
(
  SELECT CustomerID, League, HomeTeam AS Team, Season FROM MyTable
  UNION ALL
  SELECT CustomerID, League, AwayTeam AS Team, Season FROM MyTable
)
  combined_view
GROUP BY
  Team, League, Season
ORDER BY
  total DESC
```

Comment: Hey, @MatBailie thank you for trying. Unfortunately after creating indexes and used your code than running time been a little bit longer. Ps, I cannot be able to add or remove something from the table.

Comment: Then you need to consider alternative avenues than optimisation.  Is the accurate query that I added *required*, or is your estimated *`SUM(COUNT(DISTINCT)+COUNT(DISTINCT))`* sufficient?  If yours is sufficient, is a simpler estimate reasonable; just remove the `DISTINCT`?  What's more important, accuracy or execution time?  You need to clearly explore your requirements and problem statement, it's not uncommon for a requirement to be built on the notion that it will be easy, but upon realisation that it's hard/slow/expensive, a simpler requirement is put forward.

Comment: Exactly. First, when I asked this question I was thinking I had a silly query for time but looks like I should choose Time/Accuracy!

Comment: @Axis - Did either pair of indexes improve the execution time of your query *(from your Original Post)*?

Comment: @Axis - Also, please could you include the table definition including existing indexes, etc?  Also, how come you can add indexes but not columns?

Comment: I am sorry @MatBailie I missed it. It has only indexes that you wrote not any more indexes. I could not understand "Also, how come you can add indexes but not columns" I typed which you suggested and it was success but did not change any execution times, unfortunately.

Comment: You wrote `Ps, I cannot be able to add or remove something from the table.`, I understood that to mean that you can't test the `ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE ADD COLUMN` option?

Comment: When you added the suggested indexes, did it make any difference to the execution time?  What was the execution time before adding the indexes?  What was the execution time after adding the indexes?  Did you try all four potential indexes, or just one pair of indexes?

Comment: Sorry English is my second language :( I meant I cannot change my table or create any table. I should keep the original table. Yes before was 1min57 sec (my original) then your code was 2 min 24 sec after indexes both I typed not seperate then was 2 mins 27sec

Comment: @Axis - Literally speaking that means you can't add an index either.  The column I'm suggesting adding is a computed column, it's not a "real" column : You don't insert data in to it, MySQL calculates the value in the computed column for you, based on the other columns you already have.  Why is it that you are able to add indexes but not computed columns?  *(Or, more importantly, what is the **full** list of things you are or are not allowed/able to do?)*

Comment: BTW, your English is better than many Native English Speakers'.

Comment: May as well use datatype `YEAR` and function `YEAR(MatchDate)`.

Comment: The bigger `UNION` will _probably_ be slower.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this?

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(A.MatchDate, '%Y') as 'Season',  
       case c.col
         when 'home' then A.HomeTeam
         when 'away' then A.AwayTeam
       end as Teams,
       A.League, count(distinct A.CustomerID) as "totalnum" 
        FROM MY_TABLE A
        cross join ( select 'home' as col union all select 'away') c
     GROUP BY League, Teams, Season
ORDER BY totalnum DESC
```

See the results in SQL Fiddle: new: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dd0335/11  (previous: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dd0335/9)

Comment: Almost same execution time

Comment: Of course. I have a million rows table included teams, match, Leagues and so on. I need unique customer  (which is important) who watch each team but rows stores match so means Two teams, my idea is to add each customer per two teams so find the number of watches. Final idea is to find total watch per Leagues and per Teams.(I will use this result for another data platform so I cannot use in two different column, unfortunately)

Comment: Sorry, I meant MySQL's execution plan (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/execution-plan-information.html).  I've simplified my answer.

Comment: MySQL doesn't do anything we didn't ask him to do.  To be sure about the count(distinct): if the same customer watched the same team playing multiple times in a year, you only want to count that as one?

Comment: It is totally fine. Related to connection of competition some customers can connect many times of the same match so I wanted to avoid just this otherwise all customers in same year totally fine

Comment: Then, perhaps normalizing your schema may give you a performance gain: two tables, one containing the matches, one the visits (containing only customer id and match id).  There will be a lot less data to read.